# Python recognise with and without quotation marks

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

I have this line of code that works.

```
price = df1.loc[:, ['price', 'date']]
```

I need to emulate this is as a loop with other metrics like sales and revenue. Is this possible? i.e How do I get Python to reference a word in the list both with and without quotation marks?

```
listx = [price,sales, revenue]
for a in listx:
    a = df1.loc[:, ['a', 'date']]
```

Comment: Can you add sample data and expected output in your question?

Comment: Does `listx` is a list of variables or strings?

Comment: Python doesn't know what price, sales and revenue are when defining the list. But the end goal is to make it look like the way I defined price above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you could do something like this, using a list comprehension:

```
listx = ['price','sales', 'revenue']
price, sales, revenue=[df1.loc[:, [a, 'date']] for a in listx]
```

---

For a general way, this could be an approach using `globals`:

```
listx = ['price','sales', 'revenue']
for a in listx:
    globals().update({a:df1.loc[:, [a, 'date']]})
```

As is requested in the comments, please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in the future.

Comment: Is there a way to do the second line without having to list them without quotation marks? In a more general way perhaps?

Comment: I'm getting: "KeyError: 'Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing labels is no longer supported, "

Comment: It seems like maybe there isn't at least one label in the columns of df1. All the column names exits in df1? Maybe with a sample of the dataframe we maybe could find the reason of the error. @arv

Comment: Think I've worked out why.  Sorry is there a way to set index, and drop na in the same line using this method? Like ```price = df1.loc[:, ['price', 'date']].set_index('date').dropna(how='all')```

Comment: Yes, you answered your own question, that'll be the way @arv

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way using the existing list comprehension code?

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is to save it in a dict:

```py
metrics = {}
listx = ['price', 'sales', 'revenue']
for a in listx:
    metrics[a] = df1.loc[:, [a, 'date']]
```

Now you can access the metrics with `metric['sales']` etc.

---

Maybe I misunderstood your question. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in the future.

Comment: I'm getting: "KeyError: 'Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing labels is no longer supported."

Comment: One of the elements in your list is not in the columns. See [official documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#deprecate-loc-reindex-listlike) for more information. Check the spelling of your list elements.